# Export HTML table to MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, sql, html-table

Let's say I have an HTML table.

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Password</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User_1</td>
<td>Password_1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User_2</td>
<td>Password_2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need a script that creates the COLUMNS in the TH tag to a MySQL table, and then inserts the data that's in the TD tag. How to do that?

Comment: `<?php # insert code here ?>` is a good start.

Comment: Is it one time thing? Then do it by hands. Just find table editor, create table and copy and paste data.

Comment: It has more than 80k rows.

Comment: Hey, please check my answer. I tested it and it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be simple yet very fun at the same time.

I'd suggest using a PHP DOM parser. (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

1. Create the table with its columns (id, username, password) in MySQL by hand.
2. Place the html file (with html table) on the webserver.
3. Place the PHP DOM parser class on the webserver (http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)
4. ???
5. Awesomeness!

   ```
   require_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

   $table = file_get_html('table.html');

   foreach($table ->find('tr') as $tr){ // Foreach row in the table!
      $username = $tr->find('td', 0)->plaintext; // Find the first TD (starts with 0)
      $password= $tr->find('td', 1)->plaintext; // Find the second TD (which will be 1)
       echo "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password') <br />"; // Do your insert query here!
   }
   ```

Output (i tested this):

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES (NULL, '', '') 
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES (NULL, 'User_1', 'Password_1') 
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES (NULL, 'User_2', 'Password_2')
```

So remove the first `<tr>` from the html file, since it's the table heading.

Comment: Gonna try this right now, thanks!

Comment: Just tried it, sorry it took me a lot of time, had to do 81 columns. I get Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: Did you include the simple html dom class?

Comment: I had to edit the MAX_FILE_SIZE, it's running right now, will reply with results.

Comment: Ah, that table must be pretty big then!

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Comment: Oh I forgot to edit it in PHP.ini.

Comment: It works like a charm! Just takes a lot of time and memory to execute. Thanks!